# webform2pdf blank page

Tags: 7, webforms

I am using [webform2pdf](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform2pdf). I'm having an issue with the download PDF button; it goes to a blank page when it goes to a path like **/node/3/webform-results/downloadpdf**. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: See the d.o.[page](https://www.drupal.org/node/158043) on troubleshooting the WSOD death for finding the error in Drupal blank pages.

Answer (score 1):

what PHP errors do you get when errors are set to be shown on the website from your php.ini or htaccess file. webform2pdf has a dependency on TCPDF library and they often become out-of-sync with one another. So as a developer you need to be sure you're using the recommended versions of the required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I actually went on a long shot and downloaded the tcpdf straight from http://www.tcpdf.org and created a folder named /sites/all/libraries/ from there I took the tcpdf folder and dropped it in that directory. Fixed everything. The Drupal module for TCPDF does not work.